# Prevent new file manager window when USB disk wakes up

Tags: usb, disk

OS: Xubuntu 16.04, USB disk 1TB.
The USB disk hibernates when idle for a while and when the drive is accessed, it wakes up; sofar expected behavior.
My "complaint": when the disk wakes up, a new File Manager window is opened, as if the USB plug was just inserted and the disk auto-mounted. Not an error, just annoying behavior.
Any tips or suggestions?
NB. I would prefer to keep the hibernate behavior.
Thanks in advance,
Willem

Comment: Will it work to fix it according to the following link? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Stop_cluttering_the_desktop

Comment: @sudodus: that indeed fixes it. With a twist though. When I really insert a new USB drive, there is also no FM window. But that is ok, for reallt new mounted drives I receive a notification. So apparently the 'I am online again' signal of the drive is treated as 'I was just mounted'. Ok, good to know.  Will formulate this in the answer. Thanks mate.

Comment: Can we post an answer or close as duplicate?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I think WillemK intends to post an answer.

Comment: Indeed. Slight delay caused by my coffee maker ;-))

Answer (score 1):

The solution to prevent the opening of a FM window is: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Stop_cluttering_the_desktop

My **Xubuntu 16.04** machine seems to act upon a 'wake-up from hibernation' signal as if it came from a newly mounted drive.
The only difference now is that a new mount gives a notification on my screen and the wake-up of the drive does not.

Comment: @sudodus: See editted answer.